# Grails. Submit to controller/action on select change

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-forms-plugin

I would like to submit a form to an action on select box change (when an item is selected I need to update another select box and maybe other fields). The following code will submit the form to the controller/action defined on form element.

```
 <g:select onchange="submit()"/>
```

How could I submit the form to a custom action ?
I think to put a hidden action submit on the page and trigger a click on it when selecting an item in the select box, but hopping there is a more elegant way.
The project use jquery, so the prototype library isn't available.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Grails can use JQuery instead of prototype for AJAX.  Install the JQuery plugin and add `grails.views.javascript.library="jquery"` to your Config.groovy, and `remoteLink`, `formRemote`, etc, will all use JQuery.

Comment: ok, thanks, what about submitting on select change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an unusal use-case to submit the whole form, just because one combo box is changed. Usually the following is sufficient submitting only the new value of the combo box.

```
<g:form id="thisForm" action="yourFormAction">
    <g:select                       
        onchange="${remoteFunction(
            action:'yourOnChangeAction',
            update:'thisForm', 
            params:'\'thisInputField=\' + this.value' )}"
        value="${value}" 
        name="productDependencyType" 
        from="${values}" />
</g:form>
```

However, if your REALLY want to have all other form fields to be submitted as well, I guess it would be the best, to have one dispatching action and your input box sets some hidden field before submitting to the standard form-action. Hidden submit buttons are scary :)

Comment: yes, that's what I wanted, but I need the all page to be refreshed, what should I set as update ?

Comment: To gather the inputs of your whole form, you can use:
**var data = $('#thisForm').serialize()** [cd JQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: you should not reload the complete page, but if you want that, call window.location.reload() in the onComplete function of `remoteFunction`.